# Is the cost incurred when partitioning date tables in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, partition, bigdata, database

BigQuery quotes this command for creating a partition from existing tables:

```
bq partition mydataset.sharded_ mydataset.partitioned
```

(see [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables))

But when I run this, I see that the data is actually getting moved. Since selecting data from raw large tables is very expensive, I wonder how Google applies billing for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The `bq partition` CLI command leverages copy jobs rather than queries, which don't incur execution costs (but you do still get charged for the persisted storage that it may generate).

If you're using the CLI, copy jobs can be specified using the [bq cp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#copytables) command.